# as3 how to repeat part movieclip timeline number of times from label to label

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I have a movie clip with about 7 lapels on the timeline, I want each part of the label to repeat 2 times and until the end of the timeline, and no code on the movie clip timeline at all.  I am trying to do it with if statements and it is just not working out, is there a way to do it using a for loop?

```
var repeat:Number = 2;
var repeating:Number = 1;
var mcFramelabel = 'label1';
var labelNum:Number = 1;
mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, repeatLabel);
function repeatLabel(e:Event):void
{
if (mc1.currentLabel == mcFrameLabel)
{
    repeatIt();
}
}

function repeatIt(){
var labelNumCont:Number;
if (repeating < repeat && mcFramelabel == 'label1'){
    repeating++;
    mc1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}else if (repeating < repeat && mcFramelabe != 'label1'){
    repeating++;
    labelNum++;
    labelNumCont = labelNum - 1;
    mcframelabel = 'label'+labelNumCont;
    mc1.gotoAndPlay(mcframelabel)
}else if (repeating == repeat){
    repeating = 1;
    labelNum++
    mcFramelabel = 'label'+labelnum;
    mc1.gotoAndplay(mcfameLable);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you're loading swfs into your movieclip, and want to use the labels from the swf, be sure you reference the swf's timeline labels and not the container movieclip's labels.  That said, the basic implementation remains the same if you want to control playback outside of the movieclip (save for the need of a different trigger event).

```
mc1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tick);
var count:Object = {};

function tick(e:Event):void {
    if (mc1.currentFrameLabel != null) { // If the playhead is resting on a frame with a label...
        for each (var label in mc1.currentLabels) { // loop through the mc's list of labels.
            if (count.hasOwnProperty(label) == false) { // if we don't have a value for this label
                count[label] = 1; // store it
                break; // break the loop, and allow the playhead to continue.
            } else if (count[label] < 2) { // If we haven't met our desired count
                count[label]++; // increment
                mc1.gotoAndPlay(label); // and go back to that label
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I believe that should do the trick.  Of interest, you may want to look at [MovieClip.currentLabels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabels).

---

Keep in mind, all relevant code is run completely through during each frame update.  A loop will execute all its code in the millisecond it was called, so this is not what you want in this case.

You could try storing a count for each label's playback and check that count just before each label.  For example, assuming you have the following timeline setup:

```
label1                 check()   label2
   |          |          |          |
   0          1          2          3
```

Your code would look like this...

```
var count:Object = {};
function check():void {
    // Make sure this label exists in our count
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(mc1.currentLabel) == false) {
        count[mc1.currentLabel] = 1;
        mc1.gotoAndPlay(mc1.currentLabel);
    }
    // If the label is already present in the count, then this will be our
    // second playthru, and we can let the playhead continue to the next label.
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to replay that frame 10 times, you could augment it this way...

```
var count:Object = {};
var repeat:int = 10;

function check():void {
    // Make sure this label exists in our count
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(mc1.currentLabel) == false) {
        count[mc1.currentLabel] = 1;
    } else { // increment the count
        count[mc1.currentLabel]++;
    }

    // If we haven't reached our goal, go back to the label.
    if (count[mc1.currentLabel] != repeat) {
        mc1.gotoAndPlay(mc1.currentLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is I have no code in the movieclip that is being loaded, all the code is in a package, so I will have to use a event to know what frame the movie is at. the movieclip is a container and a swf is loaded into it and when one swf is done another is loaded into the same movieclip.  I have the loader working good.  But to repeat frames between the labels without having code in the loaded swf is what I am trying to do.